# PK incremented even on insert error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a kind of issue with my stored procedure.

Here is the procedure :

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.procedure_name','P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.procedure_name;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procedure_name(        
            @someParameters type,
            @idCreated int = NULL OUTPUT
        )
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO dbo.table(some_parameters)
        VALUES(@someParameters);

        SET @idCreated = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());

        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000), @ErrorSeverity int;
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, 1);
    END CATCH;
GO
```

The problem occurs when I make a **bad execution** of this procedure (like trying to put a bad `FK`in one of the parameters). I catch the error, so far so good, but when I check the **identity key** of the table, it has been **incremented** in the **same way** as it would be for a **correct request** (*by 1*).

This is not a big issue, but I would like to keep the database as clean as possible, not have a lot of unexplicable jumps in my PK column.

Do I have to reseed the key in the catch block ? This seems weird to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you would have to re seed. But don't do this. If you want a sequence there are other solutions for this. Use identities as they are built here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design and works as expected.  The intent of an identity column is not to supply a gap-free sequence of numbers, but to supply a simple way to assign a numeric unique identifier.

Do not reseed the key.  This is a design-time operation and not something you should do at run-time.

If you need the numbers to be consecutive, find another approach.

Comment: Copy that. Like i said, it was not a big issue anyway. Thanks for the additional information.